# Load page inside Body element inside page which was loaded in other Body element?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I have 3 pages.
 1. A blank page, where is having only a @Body. I am keeping this as a spaceholder where the other pages is shown.
 2. A second page which having controls and a @Body as well and it's loaded inside the 1st - blank page.
 3. A third page which is supposed to be placed inside the @Body of the second page without destroying it's content.

anyway when I try to load with `NavigationManager.NavigateTo( "/page3" );` from the second page - the content of the second page is destroyed and replaced with the content of page3.

- How can I load contend into the secondary page without destroying it ?!

[image]

Comment: We love code, share your code.

Comment: Sounds like you need a shared component. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Updated the post. Will make a sample if the explanation is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a default `@Body` spaceholder only on layout component, inheriting from `LayoutComponentBase`. You first blank page surely does so, otherwise the page2 won't be displayed. But to have a `@Body` placeholder on page2 and to use routing to navigate to page3 you need to have page2 also be a layout.
So what you actually need to do is to make page2 also a layout, set it's layout to page1, and set page3 layout to page2. And if you want to display at some route just page2 with blank `@Body` you should set to this route a completely blank page and set it's layout to page2.
Something like:

BlankPageLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@Body
```

Page2Layout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@layout BlankPageLayout

<some html>
    @Body
</some html>
```

Page2.razor

```
@page "/page2"
@layout Page2Layout
```

Page3.razor

```
@page "/page3"
@layout Page2Layout

<some html></some html>
```

now navigating to [page2](http://page2) you'll get just a Page2Layout and navigating to [page3](http://page3) you'll get a Page2Layout with page3 content inside.